# SQLite CGI Programming (SQLITE_CANTOPEN)

Tags: sqlite, cgi

When I am trying to use sqlite3_exec to insert new data into the database, it returns error 14 (SQLITE_CANTOPEN). But when I am using sqlite3_prepare_v2 to select, it works fine. Is there an issue with permissions? How to fix it?

```
sprintf(temp, "INSERT INTO owned (pid, oname, okey, ohp, oatt, odef) VALUES (%d, %c%s%c, %c%s%c, %d, %d, %d);", pid, 34, poname, 34, 34, passkey, 34, sqlite3_column_int(res3,0), sqlite3_column_int(res3,1), sqlite3_column_int(res3,2));

error = sqlite3_exec(conn, temp, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: cgi and database are both in usr/lib/cgi-bin/ dir

Comment: sqlite3_exec() internally used sqlite3_prepare, which doesn't have any differences from prepare_v2 regarding the database file. Is the surrounding code identical?